# CSS: Cannot center a div

Tags: css

My markup page contains 2 elements as follows:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
Body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div#bg {
    height:320px;
    width:850px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
#black {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width:33%;
    height:13%;
    margin:90px auto 0;
}

...

<ul id="black"></ul>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T73La/)

I want to place `black` inside `bg`, centered 13% below its top margin. Unfortunately I can't get `black` centered ! What I'm getting is:
[image]

Can anyone tell me please how to center `black` keeping `bg` at its place?
Thanks

Comment: quick question. If you want the unordered list to display inside the div, why don't you actually place it inside the div like so: <div><ul></ul></div> ?

Comment: The margin isn't behaving as you seem to be expecting due to absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `margin:90px auto 0;` to `margin:90px 33.5% 0;`

As you use `position:absolute`, `margin:auto` does not do what you would like to achieve anymore. I divided your container's width by two (33% / 2) and substracted it from the now relative left-position (50%), which is 50% - 16.5% = 33.5%.

Comment: Your solution was not as sophisticated as i'd like it to be, using "auto" to achive centering but it is the only solution that worked...

Answer (score 1):

When you try to center the absolute positioned element then this trick does the work.

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%
margin-top:-(half of the height);
margin-left: -(half of the width);
```

CSS

```
#black 
{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: black;
 width:33%;
 height:13%;
 margin-top:-7%;
 margin-left:-17%;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
}
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6sCL2/1/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6sCL2/1/embedded/result/ your fiddle result doesn't center's the black

Comment: Thanks Sachin. "Black" wasn't vertically centered and when I wiped out "Height" it simply vanished..

Answer (score 0):

I would place the UL inside the DIV, and then work it out like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nDpAf

Set the left and right values as % on the UL rather than setting the width.

Comment: The same would work outside of the background DIV by the way.